# Rails - Getting Cucumber Installed w PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, cucumber

How can I install cucumber to use PostgreSQL instead of SQLite?

Thanks

Comment: Did you update your database.yml file already?

Comment: Completely disregarding the original question, I find it amazing to call some Rails framework cucumber... which is somehow also some kind of rail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber has nothing to do with how Rails uses the database.

You need to have your test environment set up correctly in your `config/database.yml` file:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  username: your_name
  database: a_database
```

You will also need to specify the `pg` gem in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'pg'
```